# Show data from Database Using HttURLConnection

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I'm show data from database but is not work.
That is get me the Exception : FileNotFound but the path is well.
But when I put the URL from the browser it works normally

There is my code :

```
  @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... parametro)
    {
        try
        {
            URL url  = new URL(urlMostrarClientes);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String linha = "";

            while ((linha = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                buffer.append(linha + "\n");
            }

            inputStream.close();
            bufferedReader.close();
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            return buffer.toString().trim();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.v("vampiro","ERRO : "  + e.toString());

        } catch (ProtocolException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.v("vampiro","ERRO : "  + e.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.v("vampiro","ERRO : "  + e.toString());
        }

        return "ERRO";
    }
```

Comment: Please post your stacktrace

Comment: Just for your info don’t use string buffer for performance issues

Comment: @Code does my answer helped?

Answer (score 0):

Three ways of solving problem :

1. *file:///yourFilePath*
2. *Paths.get(yourPath).toUri().toURL() //java nio way*
3. *File(“path_to_file”).toURI().toURL();
    //java io way*